# How to wrap the text inside the SVG polygon without cutting the text

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, width

I have used SVG polygon in the sunburst which I got from GitHub. The text that is rendered on the breadcrumb is not fitting the polygon. I have changed the width of the polygon but it isn't working. How do I wrap the text inside that svg:polygon?

This is the code:

```
var entering = g.enter().append("svg:g");

entering.append("svg:polygon")
    .attr("width",100)//I have changed the width but it is not working
    .attr("height",100)
    .attr("points", breadcrumbPoints)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name);
    })
//  .style("fill", function(d) { return colors[d.name]; });

entering.append("svg:text")
    .attr("x", (b.w + b.t)/2)
    .attr("y", b.h / 2)
    .attr("dy", "0.35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
    });
```

The sunburst looks like this.
The text is not fitting into the polygon breadcrumb and is not displayed correctly. Some part of the text has been cut.

[image]

Comment: This is the breadcrumb points code.

function breadcrumbPoints(d, i) {
        var points = [];
        points.push("0,0");
        points.push(b.w + ",0");
        points.push(b.w + b.t + "," + (b.h / 2));
        points.push(b.w + "," + b.h);
        points.push("0," + b.h);
        if (i > 0) { // Leftmost breadcrumb; don't include 6th vertex.
            points.push(b.t + "," + (b.h / 2));
        }
        return points.join(" ");
    }

Comment: can you provide a plnkr or jsfiddle with the working codee!?

Comment: Hi,
Here is the jsfiddle link :
http://jsfiddle.net/bhavana124/zv3zvur6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I would take to solve this issue is to use plain html and css. Let css take care of arranging the elements by using a small set of rules.

Instead of a svg lets create a container for the breadcrumbs

```
<div id="main">    
    <div id="sequence-container">
        <div id="sequence" class="breadcrumbs-container"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- rest of html -->
</div>
```

Lets update a little your `mouseover` function:

```
function mouseover(d) {
    // ...
    var sequenceArray = getAncestors(d);
    // updateBreadcrumbs(sequenceArray, percentageString); remove this!
    var breadcrumbs = d3.select('#sequence').selectAll('.breadcrumb-custom')
        .data(sequenceArray); // join data
    // usual update pattern 
    breadcrumbs.exit().remove();
    breadcrumbs.attr('class', 'breadcrumb-custom')
    breadcrumbs.enter()
        .append('li')
        .attr('class', 'breadcrumb-custom')
        .append('a')
        .style('background', function (d) {
            return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name);
        })
        .style('border-left-color', function (d) {
            return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name);
        })
        .html(function (d) {
            return d.name
        });
    // ...
}
```

And we will also need to update the `mouseleave` function:

```
function mouseleave(d) {
    // ...
    // Remove breadcrumbs
    var breadcrumbs = d3.select('#sequence').selectAll('.breadcrumb-custom')
        .data([]);
    breadcrumbs.exit().remove();
    // ...
}
```

You had a function in charge of breadcrumb initialization, we will also need to remove the call to the function:

```
function createVisualization(json) {
    // initializeBreadcrumbTrail(); remove!
}
```

And now lets declare the css rules (got them from here https://css-tricks.com/triangle-breadcrumbs/) in order to get the visual aspect we want to achieve:

```
#sequence-container {
  width: auto;
  height: 80px;
}
.breadcrumbs-container {
   list-style: none;
   overflow: hidden;
   font: 18px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
}
.breadcrumbs-container li {
   float: left;
}
.breadcrumbs-container li a {
   color: white;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 10px;
   padding: 15px 0 10px 55px;
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   float: left;
}
.breadcrumbs-container li a:after {
   content: " ";
   display: block;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-top: 50px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
   border-left: 30px solid;
   border-left-color: inherit;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   margin-top: -50px;
   left: 100%;
   z-index: 2;
}
.breadcrumbs-container li a:before {
   content: " ";
   display: block;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-top: 50px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
   border-left: 30px solid white;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   margin-top: -50px;
   margin-left: 1px;
   left: 100%;
   z-index: 1;
}
.breadcrumbs-container li:first-child a {
   padding-left: 10px;
}
```

The end result looks like this:
[image]

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zv3zvur6/1/

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: Hi ,for getting equal width for all the breadcrumbs ,I kind of changed the polygon points ..

This is the code that I have used :

Comment: @torresomar, this is very helpful and works nicely. But now with mouseover, moving left or right within an arc (siblings) vs moving down the hierarchy does not update the breadcrumb. Is there a way to correct this?

Answer (score 1):

To have the breadcrumbs update while moving mouse from left to right within a level(siblings) change var breadcrumbs to this:

```
var breadcrumbs = d3.select('#sequence').selectAll('.breadcrumb-custom')
    .data(sequenceArray, function(d) { return d.name + d.depth; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your response. For increasing the size and for getting equal width of the breadcrumbs , I have changed the polygon points and my code now looks like this.

```js
function breadcrumbPoints(d, i) {
       var points = [];
       points.push("0,0");
       points.push(b.w*2 + ",0");
       points.push(b.w*2 + b.t + "," + (b.h / 2));
       points.push(b.w*2 + "," + b.h);
       points.push("0," + b.h);
       if (i > 0) { // Leftmost breadcrumb; don't include 6th vertex.
         points.push(b.t + "," + (b.h / 2));
       }
       return points.join(" ");
     }

     // Update the breadcrumb trail to show the current sequence and percentage.
     function updateBreadcrumbs(nodeArray, percentageString) {

       // Data join; key function combines name and depth (= position in sequence).
       var g = d3.select("#trail")
           .selectAll("g")
           .data(nodeArray, function(d) { return d.name + d.depth; });

       // Add breadcrumb and label for entering nodes.
       var entering = g.enter().append("svg:g");

       entering.append("svg:polygon")
           .attr("points", breadcrumbPoints)
           .style("fill", function(d) { return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name); })
         //  .style("fill", function(d) { return colors[d.name]; });

       entering.append("svg:text")
           .attr("x", (b.w + b.t/2))
           .attr("y", b.h /2)
           .attr("dy", "0.36em")
           .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
           .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
           .style("fill", "white");

       // Set position for entering and updating nodes.
       g.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
         return "translate(" + i * (b.w + b.s)*2+ ", 0)";
       });

       // Remove exiting nodes.
       g.exit().remove();

       // Now move and update the percentage at the end.
       d3.select("#trail").select("#endlabel")
           .attr("x", (nodeArray.length + 0.5) * (b.w*2 + b.s))
           .attr("y", b.h / 2)
           .attr("dy", "0.36em")
           .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
           .text(percentageString)
       .style("fill", "green")

       // Make the breadcrumb trail visible, if it's hidden.
       d3.select("#trail")
           .style("visibility", "");

     }
```

Comment: Please do let me know,if there is any other easy way .Thanks in advance